# What is the fastest way to build R-tree in neo4j spatial?

Tags: neo4j, spatial

I want to load millions of spatial data into neo4j to build spatial index. When I test with 1M spatial points, it takes about 1 hour to build the R-tree index. What is the maximum throughput of building spatial index in neo4j. In my case, it is 1,000,000/3600s = 277 nodes/s. Of course it is too slow. Is there other alternatives to speed up the spatial index construction. For comparison, to build Gist index in postgres takes only 30 seconds on the same dataset.